# Javascript not working? When I click the text, the menu doesn't dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a home page for a website idea I have, and I'm trying to make a dropdown menu when I hit Log In in the top right. Sort of like the help button next to the search bar on this site. I know how to do the drop down menu, but I've checked my HTML, my CSS, and my JavaScript, and I can't find anything wrong. I even copied code segments from a dropdown menu that works and copied it into my code to see if it would work, but it still doesn't. Anybody have any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code.

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.login').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
.login {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 105px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfile.css" />
  <title>Fandoms and Stuff</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--ADD ENDING BODY TAG-->
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="left">
      <li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Fandoms.html">Fandoms</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="login">Log In</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Test</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>(this is where I put my long description.)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Best I can tell is that your CSS is causing the `Login` link to be covered by another element. If I ditch your CSS, it works.

Comment: Specifically the `padding: 50px;` under `.nav a` seems to be the issue. Give that rule a background and border, and you'll see the issue. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6hwxsu0p/

Comment: @squint Okay, so I commented out the jumbotron in the html, but i still don't see anything. Is that what you mean by your comment?

Comment: @squint And I got rid of the css but I still didn't see it come down.

Comment: @connexo what did you do to get it to work?

Comment: I just put your code in a snippet, and it worked.

Comment: @connexo Oh I see it now. I ran the snippet but when I copied it into the file and ran it in the browser, it still didn't show up.

Comment: Might be a problem with loading external JS when using `file://` protocol. Loading jQuery will result in file:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js which won't work. Or are you using Apache or some other web server to test your stuff locally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79592/discussion-between-l1zzy-and-connexo).

Comment: You should answer (undelete) your own answer, mark it as accepter and remove the answer from the question/title

Comment: @K3N I can't accept my answer for 20 hours. And what do you mean by remove the answer from the title?

Comment: @l1zZY The [solved] does not need to be there. When an answer is accepted it will be marked such.

Comment: @K3N Oh yeah. I just put that there bc I solved it and couldn't mark my own answer as accepted for the next couple of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I was being stupid. I added

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>`

to the `<head>` element and it worked fine. Thanks for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The padding in this class is blocking your access to the link "login". If you make the padding: 0 you can then click the link and get a response. I did not look further into the toggle but the current problem you have is not being able to click the link.

```
.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `0px` but nothing happened. I also did that when I commented out the `.jumbotron`

Comment: In my test I was testing whether the function was firing with a console.log(); The original script didn't fire so i adjusted the padding to 0 and the log came through. Use Firebug in Firefox to look at your code and play with it on the fly. Like I said In my answer, I didn't look into the actual dropdown menu once I figured out your link was blocked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see display: none on .dropdown-menu.

Try adding display: none to your .dropdown-menu so it will be display: none when page loads and change it to display: block when you toggle it by clicking .login.